# magento 2 : Product listing show most viewed products first

Tags: magento2, product-listing

i want to show products in order of most viewed on listing page i did below changed on my list.phtml but it seems not working

**file : app/design/frontend/colora/colora_default/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml**

modified

```
$_productCollection = $block->getLoadedProductCollection();
```

to

```
$_productCollection->getSelect()->
            joinInner('report_event AS _table_views',
                ' _table_views.object_id = e.entity_id',
                'COUNT(_table_views.event_id) AS views')->
            group('e.entity_id')->order('views ASC');
```